# using 3D images in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing a site in asp.net mvc 2.0.I already implemented image uploading functionality.
Here while ordering the shirts by user,user will see the front side of the t-shirt.
But now my client want to see both front and back side of the t-shirts.Is it possible to implement like this in asp.net mvc 2.0.I think it is about 3D views.how to implement this in asp.net mvc 2.0.
is there any example applications on this ?.If it is there please send me the link.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by 3D views but can't you simply have two `img` tags in your view representing the front and the back image:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("Images", new { id = "front1" }) %>" alt="front" />
<img src="<%= Url.Action("Images", new { id = "back1" }) %>" alt="back" />
```

Where `Images` represents a controller action serving an image given its id.